# Odoo webshop minimum order quantity

Tags: javascript, python, controller, web, odoo

Any ideas how I can implement a minimum order quantity on the webshop?
I've added a field(website_min_order) for this to product.template. Now I need to implement a checker to see if the quantity is equal or greater than this field.

Do I need to implement this in de web controller, or in the js?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your attempt so far. This website is about helping people with specific problems. If you can show you've made some effort you're more likely to get help.

Answer (score 1):

You should lock the "add to cart" button via JS unless the qty matches your settings. You can expose the value via data attribute in the template.

That will work for the single product page but you'll need to handle the cart view too. In that case you should hook to the qty in the cart and highlight the the product that does not match the qty.

Finally,  you should prevent the checkout process if any products does not match the qty, and this might require an override of checkout controller too.